# Calling assembly in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, constraints, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline uint
xchg(volatile unsigned int *addr, unsigned int newval)
{
   uint result;
   asm volatile("lock; xchgl %0, %1" : "+m" (*addr), "=a" (result) : "1" (newval) : "cc");

return result;    
}
```

Can some one tell me what this code does exactly? I mean I have an idea or the parts of this command. "1" newval is the input, "=a" is to flush out its previous value and update it. "m" is for the memory operation but I am confused about the functionality of this function. What does the "+m" sign do? Does this function do something like m=a; m = newval; return a

Answer (score 6):

`=` and `+` are constraint modifiers.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers

> `=' Means that this operand is
>   write-only for this instruction: the
>   previous value is discarded and
>   replaced by output data.
>
> `+' Means that this operand is both
>   read and written by the instruction.

Basic constrains are here

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints

> `m` A memory operand is allowed, with
>   any kind of address that the machine
>   supports in general.
>
> ..`1`.. An operand that matches the
>   specified operand number is allowed.
>   If a digit is used together with
>   letters within the same alternative,
>   the digit should come last.

'a' is i386 specific

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints

> a The a (eax) register.

Answer (score 2):

there are `constraints`. They are not variables, but modes, like the "w", "r", "r+" of `fopen()`

some of them are described here

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

part 6. More about constraints.

And the last "cc" is clobber.

> If our instruction can alter the condition code register, we have to add `"cc"` to clobber list.

Full format of asm is

```
   asm ( assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```